# Kendo dialog not expanding to width of bootstrap 4 form group

Tags: css, kendo-ui, telerik, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 form group with a simple text input.  I am using it within a kendo dialog, however the dialog isn't automatically expanding so that the label's text and the input are all on a single line.  I have played around with the CSS but can't figure out what is causing the issue.  See the below dojo link.

https://dojo.telerik.com/EQuwayex

Answer (score 0):

You can change your "test" div to following. I set a fixed with for the label and then reduced the textbox div to col-md-6.

```
  <div id="test">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label style="width:100px" class="col-form-label">Display Text</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="displayText form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If you want to control the width of the dialog you can add a width to the Dev element and then change the width of the textbox div element.

```
  <div id="test" style="width:700px">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label style="width:100px" class="col-form-label">Display Text</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="text" class="displayText form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```